# Why trans-1-chloro-4-methylcyclohexane have a higher relative energy than trans-1-chloro-2-methylcyclohexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Both can be A,a or e,e, in 1,4 the groups are further apart -> less steric strain, why is 1,4 less stable according to experimental values?

1,2 high energy conformer's relative energy (kj/mol) is 4.05 and
1,4 high energy conformer's relative energy (kj/mol) is 4.50

Comment: It is not clear what you are comparing, what are the sources of your numbers and why you think that the 1,4-isomer is higher in energy. The e,e-isomers should be compared. The 1,4-e,e-isomer is 0 kJ/mol while the 1,2-e,e-isomer has a value of whatever a gauche CH3/Cl is worth. Both isomers have the same a,a energy which is 9,7 kJ/mol. If you mean why is the difference in energy between the e,e and a,a conformations for both isomers greater for the 1,4-isomer than the 1,2, then the difference is the gauche interaction in the 1,2-isomer. I don't think that you asked that question.

Answer (score 2):

*trans*-1-Chloro-4-methylcyclohexane (**1**) has two chair conformations, **1-ee** and **1-aa**. Conformation **1-ee** has two non-interacting functional groups, chlorine and methyl, both of which have *anti*-relationships with the $\ce{C2-C3 and C5-C6}$ bonds of the ring. Accordingly, the energy of this conformation is set at 0 kJ/mol. There is no need to try to set some absolute value to the energy because the only issue is how **1-ee** compares with conformation **1-aa**. Conformation **1-aa** has both substituents axial in gauche-relationships with the aforementioned C-C bonds. This conformation behaves as a composite of axial methylcyclohexane and chlorocyclohexane. Its energy is merely the sum of their respective [A-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_value), 9.7 kJ/mol.

Diaxial conformation **3-aa** of *trans*-1-chloro-2-methylcyclohexane has the same energy value of 9.7 kJ/mol because both groups are axial and non-interacting with each other. However, the diequatorial conformation **3-ee** has a gauche interaction between the chlorine and the methyl group. The magnitude of this interaction may be estimated.

The value of the $\ce{CH3/CH3}$ interaction in conformation **4-ee** of *trans*-1,2-dimethylcyclohexane may be estimated by dividing the energy of **4-aa** by 4 or by halving the A-value for a methyl group. The value of 3.8 kJ/mol is in accord with the difference in the heat of combustion of dimethylcyclohexanes **2** and **4**. Indeed, the heat of combustion of **4** is greater than **2** by ~5 kJ/mol.  [[https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/39/jresv39n1p49_A1b.pdf](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/39/jresv39n1p49_A1b.pdf)
]. Similarly, division of the energy of **3-aa** by 4 gives an estimated value for the $\ce{CH3/Cl}$ gauche interaction of 2.4 kJ/mol. The heat of combustion of 1,2-isomer **3** should be slightly greater than that of 1,4-isomer **1** by ~2.4 kJ/mol. In the event, *trans*-1-chloro-4-methylcyclohexane is more stable than *trans*-1-chloro-2-methylcyclohexane by ~2.4 kJ/mol. By more stable is meant, more negative heat of formation and smaller heat of combustion.

[image]